# what happens when we add origin before master while merging?

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

what is the difference between `git merge --no-ff origin/master` and `git merge --no-ff master`
when I don't origin it doesn't merge the changes.
What exactly it does. Can someone explain?

Comment: `origin/master` is your local repo's version of what's on the remote `origin`, from `git fetch`.  `master` is your local repo's `master` branch, which will be up to date with `origin/master` only if you've pulled it in.

Comment: `<remote>/<branch>` - often `origin/<branch>` -  branches are so called remote-tracking branches, they update their state while doing `git fetch`. Thus they let you do updates without checking out to other local branches, directly from remote repo - it is convenient. You can't change the history  or HEAD of remote-tracking branches (for instance, via `git reset`  command), they are updated automatically via `git fetch`.

Comment: From the other hand, in order to merge from your local master - `git merge --no-ff master` - regarding fresh updates from remote repo - you first need to update that master - via `git checkout master && git pull`. But this command is valid in case of local dancing with your branches, or experimenting.

Comment: To have a view of the differences between `master` and `origin/master`, run : `git log --graph --oneline master origin/master`